# Drupal 6/Pressflow - assign theme based on domain alias

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes, pressflow

I know modules like Mobile Tools can do what I want - but they don't work with Pressflow or Varnish.

So, what I'm hoping to do is assign the sitewide theme based on the url used to access it. For instance:

example.com <-- This gets the standard, desktop theme

m.example.com <-- This gets the cool shiny iphone-optimized theme with flashy javascript etc

I dont' want multisite because the content is the same.

I don't want a new entry in domain access because the content is already written and it would (presumably)  be a huge hassle to go back and assign it all to the new domain.

There's a Domain Context plugin for context, but it says it loads too late in the flow to be able to change the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up solving it with the recommendation from this thread:
http://drupal.org/node/984128#comment-3766156

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
   if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"stage")) {
                $GLOBALS['custom_theme'] = 'bar_stage';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/themekey with http://drupal.org/project/themekey_properties gives you the option to switch theme based on system:server_name

Comment: system:server_name turns out to break cache, but system:host works great and solves the problem.

Comment: Actually, it appears that both of these are setting session variables and thereby breaking my cache :( I'm going to need a different solution